# pass data to modal and then use the data as parameter in calling a controller not working

Tags: javascript, php, codeigniter

View:

```
<head>

 <script>
  var ABSOLUTE_PATH = '<?php echo base_url()?>';
 </script>

 </head>
```

//inside a table data

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm open-deleteModal" data-id="<?php echo $news['id']; ?>" data-toggle='modal' data-target="#deleteModal"><i class="fa fa-fw fa-trash-o"></i> Delete
```

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="deleteModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="deleteLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
                <div class="modal-content">
                    <div class="modal-header">
                    <h5 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">Delete Record</h5>
                    <button class="close" type="button" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close">
                        <span aria-hidden="true">×</span>
                    </button>
                    </div>
                    <div class="modal-body">                      
                    Are you sure you want to delete this record?</div>
                    <div class="modal-footer">
                    <button class="btn btn-secondary" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
                    <a class="btn btn-primary" id="delRowId">Delete</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
                </div>
    </div>
```

javascript placed in a footer

```
  $(document).on("click", ".open-deleteModal",function(){
      var rowId = $(this).data('id');
      $(".modal-body #delRowId").attr("href",ABSOLUTE_PATH+"admins/deletenews/"+rowId);
  });
</script>
```

controller:admins.php

```
  public function deletenews($rowid){
                $this->load->view('templates/admin_header');
                $this->load->view('admin_pages/view');
                $this->load->view('templates/admin_footer');
        }
```

the `<a class="btn btn-primary" id="delRowId">Delete</a>` should be the one calling the javascript but it does not call the controller. please help me someone....

Comment: function delete news is just for testing if the javascript is working if it changes view

Answer (score 0):

This just changes the href to proper link

```
$(".modal-body #delRowId").attr("href",ABSOLUTE_PATH+"admins/deletenews/"+rowId);
```

Need to trigger click event after changing the href for propoer link. try something like this

```
 $(".modal-body #delRowId").attr("href",ABSOLUTE_PATH+"admins/deletenews/"+rowId).click();
```

Comment: still no trigger. if i click the delete button in the modal still no action.